# Understanding Math.max()

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, methods

so I have four arrays of different lengths. I'll call them one, two, three, four.

To find the longest, I put them in an array.

```
let length = [one.length, two.length, three.length, four.length];
```

so I get something like `length = [10,54,22,4];`

Math.max works find if I do `Math.max(...length);`

but I don't understand why
`Math.max([one.length,two.length,three.length,four.length]) returns NaN.`

Comment: Math.max doesn't accept an array, just multiple arguments. That's what spread '...' does, turn an array into multiple arguments.

Comment: Google "*Math.max NaN site:stackoverflow.com*" there are tens of duplicates. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 2):

Simply because `Math.max()` attempts to convert its arguments to numbers. An array does not convert into a number, so you get NaN.

Calling `Math.max(...lengths)` splits the `lengths` array into several arguments, which works (so long as they're all numbers, of course).

Comment: So Math.max is trying to find the max number but the arrays themselves have yet to be converted by the .length method? so instead of Math.max([10,12,30,45]) it's something like Math.max([1,2,3],  [21,7,9], [54, 60,11], [24,5,63]) which it can't do b/c they're still arrays and not numbers?